# On Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

The following is the first part of a proof for **Hahn-Banach Theorem (Extension of linear functionals)** from Kreyszig's book of Functional Analysis:

[image]

I don't undertsand the blue-underlined sentence of the text above.

My questions are:

1- How each $D(g)$ is a vector space? Suppose $x_1, \ x_2 \in D(g)$ then $g(x_1) \le p(x_1)$ and $g(x_2) \le p(x_2)$. Then $g(x_1+x_2) = g(x_1)+g(x_2) \le p(x_1)+p(x_2)$ does not imply $g(x_1+x_2) \le p(x_1+x_2)$, because we have $p(x_1+x_2)\le p(x_1+x_2)$ by definition. So How $x_1+x_2 \in D(g)$?! The book has considered $a \ge 0$, so $g(ax) = ag(x) \ge ap(x)$. So the problem is just the sum inequality.

2- How $\bigcup D(g)$ is a vector space because "$C$ is a chain"? I can't see a coonection.

Comment: $g$ is supposed to be a _linear_ map, so $\mathscr{D}(g)$ is a linear subspace _by definition_ of a linear map. And we have the condition that $g(x) \leqslant p(x)$ for all $x\in \mathscr{D}(g)$; if that doesn't hold, $g\notin E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, if a map is linear then its *domain* must closed under sum?

Comment: A linear map is a map between vector spaces [well, in some other contexts, between $R$-modules for some ring $R$] satisfying some conditions (additivity and homogeneity). By definition the domain of a linear map is a vector space.

Comment: @DanielFischer, then Eq (3) is a wrong hypothesis since we can't have $f$ to be linear at the same time $f\le p$, since p is subadditive?

Comment: Of course it's possible that $f \leqslant p$ when $f$ is linear and $p$ subadditive. Consider $f(x) = 0$ and $p(x) = \lVert x\rVert$ on a normed space. Or $f = 0$ and $p = 0$.

Comment: You could also take a look on the following books:

Bachman & Narici, Functional Analysis.

Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDEs

Angus Taylor & David C. Lay, Introduction to Functional Analysis

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not said explicitly in the proof, each $\mathcal D (g) $ is a subspace. And an
increasing union of subspaces is a subspace (this is where you use that $C $ is a chain).

As for your argument with  $a<0 $, try it for instance on $X=\mathbb R^2$, $f (x,y)=x+y $, $p (x,y)=|x|+|y|$.

Comment: Why each $D (g)$ is a subspace?

Comment: If the "domain" $Z $ of a functional is not a subspace, the functional can be trivially extended to the subspace generated by $Z $, so there is no reason to consider it a subspace to start with.

Comment: So it's a kind of definiton, i.e. we just suppose that in every time extension the domain is *chosen* to be a subspace?

Comment: I guess. It doesn't make a lot of sense to consider extensions **not** to subspaces. Or, if you want, if the domain is not a subspace, you can replace it by the subspace it generates with no harm.

Comment: By definition, a linear functional is something that satisfies $f(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$. If you have some $x,y \in D(f)$ such that $x+y \not\in D(f)$, this definition doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x,y \in D(k)=\bigcup\limits_{g\in C} D(g)$. Then $x \in D(g_1)$ and $y\in D(g_2)$ for some $g_1,g_2 \in C$. Now note that since $C$ is a chain we must have $g_1\le g_2$ or $g_2\le g_1$. Without loss of generality, assume $g_1\le g_2$. Then by definition $D(g_2) \supset D(g_1)$. Thus $x,y \in D(g_2)$. Now since $g_2 \in E$, we have
$$x+ay \in D(g_2) \subset D(g), \ \ \ \ k(x+ay)=g_2(x+ay)\le p(x+ay)$$

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you must understand that a *Linear Extension* of a functional $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is another functional $g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $V\subset U$
2. $g(x)=f(x)$, if $x\in V$

And functionals are defined in Linear subspaces.

The important thing in the proof is showing that the set $E$ is not empty, and we know it's not because $f\in E$. The other elements of $E$ will be functionals that extend $f$, i.e functionals $g:D(g)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $Z\subset D(g)$ and that satisfy the two conditions in the text, by definition $D(g)$ are linear subspaces, don't worry too much about this, for the means of the proof the important thing is that $E\neq \emptyset$, it might be the case that $f$ is the only element in $E$, it doesn't matter.

The others already answered your question about $\bigcup D(g)$ being a linear space.

And if the inequality you stated doesn't hold for any $x\in D(g)$ then it's just the case that $g\not\in E$, but again, the only important thing is that $E\neq\emptyset$.